# How to test that a date is between two other dates on rspec (Rails 3.2/rspec)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a model Deals with these attributes:

- prelaunch_date
- launch_date
- end_date

I use the "Validate timeliness" gem to validate in my models/deal.rb that launch date is between the prelaunch date and end_date:

```
 # Validates order of dates
 validates_datetime :game_launch_date, :after => :prelaunch_date
 validates_datetime :game_end_date, :after => :game_launch_date
```

**I need now to test that with rspec. How can I do that ?**
I tried the below thing but it does not work:

```
describe "validations" do
it { should_not allow_value(:prelaunch_date - 1.day).for(:launch_date) }
it { should_not allow_value(:end_date + 1.day).for(:game_launch_date) }

end
```

Comment: Would you please share the RSpec output you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have the idea but seem to be expecting too much syntax magic. You can't, for example, evaluate this: `:prelaunch_date - 1.day`.

For game launch date validation, you can do something along this:

```
describe "validation" do
  context "of game launch date" do
    let(:date) { Date.new(2013, 1, 2) }
    subject { described_class.new(:prelaunch_date => date) }

    it "requires game launch to be after prelaunch" do
      should_not allow_value(date - 1.day).for(:game_launch_date)
      should_not allow_value(date).for(:game_launch_date)
      should allow_value(date + 1.day).for(:game_launch_date)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to test it more manually. Testing that the one of the validation is setup correctly can be done somewhat like this:

```
let(:deal) { Deal.new(:pre_launch_date => Date.today) }

it "must have game launch date after pre launch date" do
  deal.game_launch_date = 1.day.ago
  deal.valid?
  expect(deal.errors[:game_launch_date]).to_not be_empty
end
```